# Why "tehnically" transforms to "thenically" automatically in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

When I type "tehnically" using [`WinEdt`](http://www.winedt.com/) it will transform into "thenically", and show in pdf that way. Why is this and how to erase it?

Comment: This is almost certainly a feature of your text editor and not TeX/LaTeX itself.  What editor are you using?  Does it have an autocorrect mode (which would appear to be misconfigured)?

Comment: Which editor do you  use?

Comment: I have downloaded newest tex editor from internet, Winedt10.0 is written. I do not know how to configure tex editor.

Comment: Please also copy and paste part of your code into your question (or best a complete mini-example), given your previous posts today this could (unlikely but possible) be related to invisible control characters in your pasted text.

Comment: I don't use WinEdt, but when this happens to me, sometimes Ctrl-Z will undo the unwanted change.  Assuming it is the "autocorrect" feature of WinEdt.  This is not a bad question.

Comment: From an old 2007 post http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_pwV5V_tK-oJ:comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.winedt/3359+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us You might have an "active string" defined as such under `Options|Settings|Active Strings.` Disable "on Type", and the function  will stop working.  I don't know whether this is germane to your 2016 problem, but give it a try.

Comment: Why do you want to spell "tehnically"? Perhaps you might try "technically"?

Comment: Four own votes is bizarre. I agree with @AFeldman that this is a reasonable question.

Comment: Off topic...really? There are so many "need help with an editor" questions, why off topic this particular one. Not to mention lots of LyX related questions.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay May be the OP shares [my problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409778/9446) and in their native language there are words correctly spelled "teh*****"?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Such an aggressive conduct about automatic spelling corrections would be a good reason for leaving the software aside. I *might* understand correcting `teh<space>` into `the<space>`, but “fixing” `teh` into `the` while typing is something I could not bear.

Answer (score 11):

This shouldn't happen. ‘teh’ is considered an active string because it often is a mistyping for ‘the’, and a macro defines auto-correction *under special conditions*. Check in your Options interface, on the right of the editor window, the contents of the file `ActiveStrings.ini`. It should contain exactly these lines:

```
STRING="teh"
  START_FILTER="~Alpha"
  END_FILTER="~Alpha"
  ENABLED=1
  MACRO="[BeginGroup;Backspace(2);Ins('he');EndGroup;]"

STRING="TEh"
  START_FILTER="~Alpha"
  END_FILTER="~Alpha"
  ENABLED=0
  MACRO="[BeginGroup;Backspace(2);Ins('he ');EndGroup;]"
```

To modify the `ActiveString.ini` file (or any of the .ini files), open the `Options interface` in the left panel, select `Active Strings` to open it:
[image]

There is a help icon, which directs you to the help for the current .ini file. Change the values to the correct ones, either by hand or by cut and paste. Once the file has been modified, validate the modifications by clicking on the leftmost icon (`Load Current Script`). If there's any syntax error, it will issue a warning. Otherwise, the modifications will be written to the script file that WinEdt reads on start, namely `WinEdt.dnt` (never write this one yourself!).

Comment: I guess the OP should change the contents of the file `ActiveStrings.ini` to match what was posted in order to fix the problem.  Does the OP need to do this in an external editor, or can it be done through the WinEdt dialogue?  Looks like a really nice editor, although sadly I assume this does not run on Wine.

Comment: It has to be done from within WinEdt, then validated clicking on the `Load Current Script` icon. What I don't understand is why the O.P. has this behaviour. Filters are defined to prevent it.

Comment: I would guess data corruption of some kind.  I don't understand the down votes, perhaps they are RTFM related.  But: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6508/90087  And as you point out, this is a strange problem, not an ordinary thing one might easily look up.  Maybe add to your answer the "hold my hand" type of details to fix the problem by modifying the string definitions.

Comment: The link to meta above is, among other things, about RTFM etiquette.

Comment: Perhaps because it about an editor, not about (La)TeX itself. But WinEdt is tightly linked to (La)TeX…

Comment: Looks like an excellent answer to me.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard I had [this same issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409778/9446). Upon reading your explanation I just commented out those two sections from the ActiveStrings.ini file, and that fixed my problem.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes,  I've just seen your post, and was going to answer when it was closed. I didn't even remember having answered for this problem!